# Plot frequency table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data which I want to generate a bar plot. However, I couldn't figure out how to make column `Var1` to represent its weight, which is given by the `Freq` column.

```
X <-structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(4L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 20L, 28L, 
30L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 
59L, 60L, 63L, 68L, 70L, 81L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "AD", "AE", 
"AF", "AG", "AI", "AL", "AM", "AO", "AP", "AR", "AT", "AU", "AX", 
"AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BM", 
"BN", "BO", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CD", 
"CG", "CH", "CI", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CR", "CU", "CV", "CW", 
"CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", 
"ES", "ET", "EU", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FM", "FO", "FR", "GA", "GB", 
"GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GP", "GR", 
"GT", "GU", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", 
"IL", "IM", "IN", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "JE", "JM", "JO", "JP", 
"KE", "KG", "KH", "KM", "KN", "KR", "KW", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", 
"LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", 
"MD", "ME", "MG", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", 
"MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NC", "NE", "NG", "NI", 
"NL", "NO", "NP", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PK", 
"PL", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RE", "RO", "RS", "RU", 
"RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SL", "SN", 
"SO", "SR", "ST", "SV", "SY", "SZ", "TC", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TL", 
"TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "US", "UY", "UZ", 
"VC", "VE", "VG", "VI", "VN", "VU", "WS", "YE", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 7L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 41L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 30L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 21L, 6L, 10L, 
24L, 4L)), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq"), row.names = c(4L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 20L, 28L, 30L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 50L, 
51L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 63L, 68L, 70L, 81L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think all you want is: `barplot(X$Freq, names.arg = X$Var1)`?

Comment: Or with `ggplot2`: `ggplot(X, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the comment of Jake Burkhead:

With this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "grey") +
  labs(title = "Frequency by country\n", x = "\nCountry", y = "Frequency\n") +
  theme_classic()
```

you'll get this result:
[image]